# Chunking a big vector to smaller ones without extra heap allocation

Tags: c++, vector, allocator, memory-pool

I need to replace 3 heap allocations for 3 instances of std::vector, with 
only one contiguous heap allocation and then share it between those 3 vectors. These vector sizes are not going to be changed, so I don't need to be worried about allocation of new contiguous storage in case of pushing or inserting elements to them. My experimental result shows I get up to 2X speed up for different sizes, when I replace these 3 vectors of size *n*, with one vector of size of *3*n*.

However, I don't know exactly how to achieve the job of making smaller vectors out of the big one, without doing any extra heap allocation.

```
std::array<std::vector<double>, 3>
chunck_vector(size_t size)
{
  std::vector<double> * underlying_vec = new std::vector<double>(3*size, 1.0);

  // how to avoid extra heap allocations in constructor of small vectors
  std::vector<double> vec0(underlying_vec->begin()         , underlying_vec->begin() + size);
  std::vector<double> vec1(underlying_vec->begin() + size  , underlying_vec->begin() + 2*size);
  std::vector<double> vec2(underlying_vec->begin() + 2*size, underlying_vec->end());

  return {vec0, vec1, vec2};
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int size = 1000;

  auto&& chunked_vecs = chunck_vector(size);

  // passing each chunk to different functions
  // each chunk should be responsible for managing its resources
  foo0(std::get<0>(chunked_vecs));
  foo1(std::get<1>(chunked_vecs));
  foo2(std::get<2>(chunked_vecs));

  return 0;
}
```

I tried writing my own vector class, which its constructor accepts two iterators specifying begin and end of the portion of the *underlying_vec* storage belongs to this vector, but it doesn't sound a clean solution when it comes to the job of freeing resources when the *underlying* vector is not accessible any more and solving the memory leakage problem.

Apparently using a customized allocator which is shared between these three vectors and allocates a contiguous memory once and assign it to the corresponding vectors seems a better solution, however since I've never written one, any hint or suggestion to help me start coding will be appreciated.

Comment: `std::vector<double> * underlying_vec = new std::vector<double>(3*size, 1.0);` is already wrong - there's no reason to `new` a `vector`

Comment: Why not use a pointer instead of vector? Which features of vector are you going to use, which a pointer doesn't have? You can [edit] your question to show an example of your code that uses the vectors.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using pairs of iterators to map out your smaller vectors to the single larger vectors.

Comment: Maybe look at [gsl::span](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/docs/gsl-intro.md#span-parameters-how-should-i-choose-between-span-and-traditional-ptr-length-parameters) (a standard proposal) [Source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span)

Comment: @UnholySheep I didn't want the storage of *underlying_vec* to be deleted when the *underlying_vec* goes out of scope, that's why I used new.

Comment: @anatolyg That's actually what I did in my first try. Since each of these small vectors need to free their corresponding portion of memory independent of each other, without accessing *underlying_vector*, I don't think it's a good idea to delete the heap allocated memory with one new call, in three different delete calls.

Comment: A `std::vector` owns its own storage. Always. You cannot make it refer to storage owned by some other object. You could try kluging something with a custom allocator which gives the vector memory that was already allocated elsewhere, and doesn't actually deallocate when told to, but it would be very fragile. Just use something other than `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of thing [gsl::span](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/docs/gsl-intro.md#span-parameters-how-should-i-choose-between-span-and-traditional-ptr-length-parameters) is designed for.

You can find an implementation [HERE](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span). It is proposed for inclusion in the `C++` standard libraries.

You can use it like this:

```
void double_data(gsl::span<int> sp)
{
    for(auto& i: sp)
        i *= 2;
}

void tripple_data(gsl::span<int> sp)
{
    for(auto& i: sp)
        i *= 3;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    auto sp = gsl::make_span(v); // the whole vector

    auto sp1 = sp.subspan(0, 5); // first 5 elements
    auto sp2 = sp.subspan(5, 5); // last five elements

    double_data(sp1); // process it like you would a container

    tripple_data(sp2);

    for(auto i: v)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 4 6 8 10 18 21 24 27 30
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I need a container instead of pointer or span to be able to free its own memory after it's done.

Comment: @AlirezaMajidi So you want to allocate one large chunk of memory and deallocate different parts of it individually?

Comment: Exactly, as I said I get better performance when I allocate a large chunk instead of 3 separate heap allocation.

Comment: @AlirezaMajidi But memory allocation doesn't work like that. You have to give back the same size chunk that you allocated. Writing an allocator would not circumvent that. The allocator would simply give the whole chuck back after all the pieces had been accounted for. This solution is really not so different. Once you have finished with all your *spans* you can deallocate the whole chunk when the vector gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::shared_ptr`, whose primary purpose is management of shared resources. First of all, create your buffer:

```
std::shared_ptr<double> underlying(new double[3 * size], std::default_delete<double[]>());
```

Here you have to use `default_delete` as an explicit deleter, so the correct `operator delete[]` is used for deallocation. BTW I heard that in C++17 you no longer need to use an explicit deleter, if you use `shared_ptr<double[]>`.

Then define your smaller containers, using the *aliasing constructor*:

```
std::shared_ptr<double> vec0(underlying, underlying.get());
std::shared_ptr<double> vec1(underlying, underlying.get() + size);
std::shared_ptr<double> vec2(underlying, underlying.get() + 2 * size);
```

Here you can use your "vectors" until the last of them goes out of scope, and when that happens, the buffer is deallocated. However, these are not vectors — e.g. they don't store their size, only the pointer to first element.

Comment: If I understood aliasing constructor correctly, it just changes where the shared_ptr points to. This means that if I have to do the copy of the object that actually shared_ptr is created over it (for serialization purpose for example), I need to copy all the underlying buffer, which I guess hurt the performance. shared_ptr aliasing constructor was a new thing to me though, thanks for pointing out.